display errors in form from a controller base
I have implemented a login form that utilizes the login controller, which serves as a base controller. While the controller functions properly, my concern lies with error handling. Regrettably, I am unable to display error messages within the form as there is no means to return error messages from the controller. I would greatly appreciate any assistance in resolving this issue.



You could try return error message using ViewBag
...
            try
            {
                await HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewBag.Error = ex.Message;
            }
...

Then use @ViewBag.Error in razor to display message.

no ViewBag in Contoller Base

You could try catch all errors in httpcontext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>()?.Error
